# Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, be differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, be differentiable on $(a,b)$. If $f$ is strictly increasing in a neighborhood of $a$.  Can we show that $f'(x)$ is bounded in  a neighborhood of $a$?

If $f$ is not strictly increasing in a neighborhood of $a$. Then $f(x)=x \sin 1/x$ shows that it is wrong. However, if we add '' If $f$ is strictly increasing in a neighborhood of $a$'', is it right then?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that $a = 0$ in your example, and clarifying that $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sqrt{x}
\end{align}
on $[0, 1]$.